# What is the canonical way to use locking with `pathos.pools.ProcessPool`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathos

Let's consider the following example:

```
from pathos.pools import ProcessPool

class A:
    def run(self, arg: int):

        shared_variable = 100
        
        def __run_parallel(arg: int):
            local_variable = 0

            # ...

            if local_variable > shared_variable:
              shared_variable = local_variable

        ProcessPool(4).map(__run_parallel, range(1000))
```

It's quite obvious to see that there's a data race in `if local_variable > shared_variable:` with `shared_variable = local_variable` when using four processes.

Consequently, I'd like to introduce a locking mechanism around the `if` block, so I tried the following:

```
from pathos.pools import ProcessPool
from multiprocessing import Lock

class A:
    def run(self, arg: int):

        lock = Lock()
        shared_variable = 100
        
        def __run_parallel(arg: int):
            local_variable = 0

            # ...

            lock.acquire()
            if local_variable > shared_variable:
              shared_variable = local_variable
            lock.release()

        ProcessPool(4).map(__run_parallel, range(1000))
```

However, I get the error `RuntimeError: Lock objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`.

In the `multiprocessing` library, it seems as if the canonical way to achieve the desired mutual exclusion would be to use a `Manager` object.

However, how to do this idiomatically in `pathos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pathos` leverages `multiprocess`, which has the same interface as `multiprocessing`, but uses `dill`. You can access it either of these ways.

```
>>> import pathos as pa
>>> import multiprocess as mp
>>> mp.Manager is pa.helpers.mp.Manager
True
```